# How to limit a plot to certain ranges

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot with a lot of data all bunched into the lower numbers, and a few outliers make the scale of the X and Y axis huge.

I don't want to delete these outliers, as they are not incorrect, but I would like to create a separate plot focussing on the data between X axis 2,000,000 views and Y axis 5,000,000 subscribers.

[Plot of Views and Subscribers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnSOW.png)

Here's how I've created the plot:

```
plot(covviddf$view_count, covviddf$subscriber_count, 
main = "Comparison between channel subscribers and video views", 
xlab = "Views", ylab = "Subscribers")
```

I thought I might just be able to specify:

```
plot(covviddf$view_count < 2000000, covviddf$subscriber_count < 5000000)
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Let this be your sample dataset with only 2 columns:

```
df<-data.frame(views=runif(250,0,1000000),subs=runif(250,0,1000000))
```

To only plot those points which have views till 200000 and subscribers till 500000 you can do something like:

```
plot(df[df$views<200000 & df$subs<500000,]$views,
     df[df$views<200000 & df$subs<500000,]$subs,
     xlab='Views',ylab='Subscribers')
```

Here's your graph:

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

I recommond to set a log scale. Or you may want to set x and y axis limites by specifying the minimum and the maximum values of each axis for your needs.

Indicating if x or y or both coordinates should be plotted in log scale:

- log = “x”
- log = “y”
- log = “xy”

OR axis limites

- xlim: the limit of x axis; format : xlim = c(min, max)
- ylim: the limit of y axis; format: ylim = c(min, max)

```r
# --- sample data 
view_count <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,90,100,110)
subscriber_count <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,190,200,210)

covviddf <- data.frame(view_count, subscriber_count)
covviddf
plot(covviddf$view_count, covviddf$subscriber_count, 
     main = "Comparison between channel subscribers and video views", 
     xlab = "Views", ylab = "Subscribers")

# set log scale for x and y ----------------------------------------------------
plot(covviddf$view_count, covviddf$subscriber_count, 
     main = "Comparison between channel subscribers and video views", 
     xlab = "Views", ylab = "Subscribers", log="xy")

# set x and y axis limites by specifying the minimum and the maximum -----------
plot(covviddf$view_count, covviddf$subscriber_count, 
     main = "Comparison between channel subscribers and video views", 
     xlab = "Views", ylab = "Subscribers", xlim=c(1,80), ylim=c(1,180))
```

**Log Scale result:**

[image]